# How to rewrite url like a sub domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my localhost project URL as:

`http://localhost/project_directory` to `http://project_directory.localhost`
and `http://localhost/project_directory/backend` to `http://backend.project_directory.localhost`
Can you help me someone how to write rule in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/272569/rewriting-main-domain-to-subdomain-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual host in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project_directory.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/public_html/project_directory"
</VirtualHost>
```

And add this line to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.0       project_directory.localhost
```

Your hosts file is located in: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Edit the hosts file with Administrator rights.

Comment: I have been using ubuntu, however, let me try

Comment: On linux the hosts file is located in  `/etc/hosts` http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3407

Comment: It's not working. It's giving error `Unable to connect`.

Comment: Are you sure your `DocumentRoot` is correctly? I use the same settings over here.

Comment: Yes I have created a directory `/var/www/mydir` and create a virtual host and wrote `DocumentRoot` as DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydir"